# How to break out from loop inside switch C++

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, break

Let's consider:

```
switch(x)
{
case something:
    {
        for(something_else : some_container)
        {
             if(a_condition)
             {
             // BREAK OUT OF THE SWITCH
             }
        }
        some_statements();
        break;
        }
}
```

How can I escape in the most elegant way from the loop which is inside a `switch` statement since I do not want to run `some_statements();`.

Certainly a well placed `goto` would nicely solve this problem, but the solution can be considered anything but elegant:

```
switch(x)
{
case something:
    {
        for(something_else : some_container)
        {
             if(a_condition)
             {
                  goto escape_route;
             }
        }
        some_statements();
        break;
        }
}
escape_route:
// Hurrah, freedom
```

And also a flag would solve this problem:

```
switch(x)
{
case something:
    {
        bool flag = true;
        for(something_else : some_container)
        {
             if(a_condition)
             {
                  flag = false;
                  break;
             }
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            some_statements();
        }
        break;
        }
}
```

But let's just say, that I am looking for other solutions for this problem for the challenge's sake (Please note: There are more statements after the switch, `return`ing is not an option).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate about the other statements after switch?

Comment: That `goto` looks okay. Don't overthink it -- you'll only make it more tangled.

Comment: Why do you consider `goto` to not be "elegant"?  It's clear, simple, and clean - pretty much the **definition** of elegant.

Comment: The loop and `some_statements` probably should be in a function. Then you can just return and let the `switch`'s `break` handle the rest. Complex stuff like loops that can `break` inside a `switch` looks overly complex to begin with.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: That throw and catch the exception can do break but may not looks elegant.

Comment: **don't** use exception handling for normal flow control.... normal flow control is _not_ an exception.

Answer (score 4):

In general this is one of the few cases, where using gotos is often considered ok. However, since c++11 **I prefer to use an immediately invoked lambda** and a return statement:

```
[&]{
    switch(x)
    {
    case something:
        {
            for(something_else : some_container)
            {
                if(a_condition)
                {
                    return ;
                }
             }
             some_statements();
             break;
         }
     }
}(); //<- directly invokes the lambda
```

And once you have this, think if you might want to put the whole block into a separate named function.

Answer (score 1):

The goto version is ok but a better alternative might be to use a function and return from it upon an exceptional condition:

```
status_t func (void)
{
  status_t status = default_value;

  switch(x)
  {
    case something:
    {
      for(something_else : some_container)
      {
        if(a_condition)
        {
          return status;
        }
      }
      some_statements();
      break;
    }
  }

  return status;
}
```

The advantage here is that it allows you to use a status variable (for error codes etc).

Another alternative is exception handling.

Comment: Exception handling as flow control? Please don't ever do that...

Comment: @Quentin Depends on what "a_condition" means, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but I'd expect OP to mention it if it were actually error handling and not program logic.

Answer (score 0):

That `goto` looks okay. Don't overthink it -- you'll only make it more tangled.

That's for the general case, though. Your specific use looks like it can be folded into a nice call to an `<algorithm>`.

```
switch(x)
{
case something:
    {
        if(std::any_of(
            begin(some_container),
            end(some_container),
            [](auto &&e) { return a_condition(e); }
        ))
            break;

        some_statements();
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice that this calls a function which does the early returning, and immediately `break`s out if it returned `true`.
Yes, you can mimick this pattern with your own function/lambda in place of `std::any_of`.
No, it's not a good idea if your function does not make sense on its own like `std::any_of` does.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably split the function into sub functions, removing your need of break inside the loop, something like:

```
void foo(/*...*/)
{
    for (auto something_else : some_container) {
         if (a_condition) {
             return;
         }
    }
    some_statements();
}
```

And then

```
switch (x)
{
    case something:  { foo (/*...*/); break; }
    case something2: { foo2(/*...*/); break; }
    case something3: { foo3(/*...*/); break; }
    // ...
}
```